# Possible to reference previous query in new select query?

Tags: sql-server, select-query

If i just created a select query and want to use the new data in a new query do I reference the previously created query as the `FROM` in a new select query? The query I just created in my database is listed as `SQLQuery1.sql` so is that what I put as the `FROM` for the new query?

Comment: Post your sample data, the code you've tried, what results you want, and what results you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a query that contains multiple select statements:

```
SELECT T1.col_a, T1.col_b, T2.col_c
FROM (SELECT col_a, col_b, ...etc...) AS T1
JOIN (SELECT col_a, col_c, ...etc...) AS T2
ON T1.col_a = T2.col_a
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use CTE (Common Table Expression).

Have a look at the following code:

```
WITH MainQuery
AS 
(
    select col1, col2, col3
    from dbo.TableName
)


select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col1
from MainQuery as a
join someotherdata as b
on a.col1 = b.col1;
```